# Laravel Query relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

*I have query with this relationships*

```
$query = ExtraDay::with([
        'credit.client'
    ]);
```

Now i am going to make searchfield filter for 'name' field which is in CLIENT model. ExtraDay model is connected to Client model via Credit model. Below there is a way how to make search for one level relationship like with(['client']);

```
$query->where('name', 'like', "%$q%")->whereHas('client', function 
($organization) use ($q) {
            $organization->where('name', 'like', "%$q%")
                ->orWhere('short_name', 'like', "%$q%");
```

But i have with(['credit.client']);  How to search field 'name' in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whereHas` works with nested relations, so use the same dot notation `credit.client`. For example:

```
ExtraDay::whereHas('credit.client', function ($client) use ($q) {
     $client->where('name', 'like', "%$q%");
})->get();
```

Comment: No, `credit.client` is needed as it's a nested relationship.

Comment: Brian, you are correct, my mistake.